# C pointer dont work

Tags: c, pointers

I have this code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int args,char*argv[])
{
    char *input_f;

    input_f=(argv+1);

    printf("%d\n",input_f);
    printf("%d\n",(argv+1));
    printf("%s\n",*(argv+1));
    printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n",*input_f);
    return 0;
}
```

But if I run it (`test.exe hi.txt`) the output will be:

`1577880`
`1577880`
`hi.txt`
`hi.txt`
`(null)`

How can I create pointer to point the `argv[1]`?
And why my code doesn't work?

**EDIT:** The program takes an file at input and the pointer `input_f` points it but at the output the `argv[1]` prints the file name but `input_f` doesn't!

Comment: What do you think argv[1] is? What do you think its value should be? What do you expect? Which part of your code is not acting as you expect?

Comment: `input_f` is not declared, and `printf("%d\n",(argv+1))` prints the address at `argv[1]` as an integer. What do you want the output to be? It's unclear what you're trying to do.

Comment: Was your compiler silent? I guess not....

Comment: Code you posted won't even compile. If you are not getting any errors or warnings, then check your compiler settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
input_f=*(argv+1);
```

instead of

```
input_f=(argv+1);
```

and

use this

```
printf("%s\n", input_f);
```

instead of

```
printf("%s\n",*input_f);
```

**Full code:**

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main(int args,char*argv[])
{
    char *input_f;

    input_f=*(argv+1);

    printf("%s\n",input_f);
    printf("%s\n",*(argv+1));
    printf("%s\n",argv[1]);
    printf("%s\n",input_f);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> why my code doesn't work?

Assuming that `input_f` is declared as:

```
char *input_f;
```

the format specifier `%s` in the `printf()`:

```
printf("%s\n",*input_f);
```

expects that given argument is of type `char *`, you are providing `*input_f`, which is of type `char`.

---

> How can I create pointer to point the argv[1]?

`argv` is of type *array of pointer to `char`*. Therefore, `argv[1]` is of type *pointer to `char`*. So, you can store it address in a *pointer to pointer to `char`*, i.e.: type `char **`:

```
char **p = &argv[1];
```